# Is discard bad for performance when doing depth testing without depth writing?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I've read that using `discard` is bad for performance because the gpu can't assume the final depth value and early Z-testing is disabled. But if I disable depth **writing** and continue with depth testing against previous passes, is this still hold and using `discard` still disables early Z-testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`discard` is a performance problem because what happens with regard to the depth test is now governed by the execution of the fragment shader which may or may not `discard` any particular fragment. Therefore, depth testing must wait until the fragment shader has executed.

However, if you turn off depth writes... that's *global* (for that draw call). All fragments being rendered will have depth writes off. So this doesn't change the relationship between the FS and the depth test. So the depth test can happen before the FS executes.

Now any state changes around rendering framebuffer interactions are not cheap. They will incur a cost at the first draw call after the change. But that cost is a cost that happens once: after the state change. It is not a cost with regard to the speed of the draw calls using that state. Think of the state change as a speed bump in your rendering process; once you're past the hump, the road is smooth.

Comment: Thanks for the complete picture of the subject